# How to switch datasources in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report and which is coming from database `MasterDB`. Now I have created a copy of the same database named `MasterArchive`. I have created parameters for databases to display in dropdown. So, When user select `MasterDB` from `select DataSource` dropdown then datasource should change according to selection.

how to change the datasource based on the selection?

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually write an expression for your connection string by clicking that `fx` button below the `Build` button. For example, the expression would be something like:

```
="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=" + Parameters!DataSource.Value
```

Comment: How to put hard coded datasource value like localhost or some server name. I only want to select database not the server name so If I hard code the server name then it would be great. If I go with your approach then it will ask me to insert both server name and database name to view the report.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no elegant way of doing this other than using dynamic SQL

So in you Dataset query it might look something like

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@datasourceParameter) + '[dbo].[myTable]'

EXEC (@sql)
```

It's rather clunky but it will work.

There does not appear to be away of editing the datasource, it seems to be set once during report execution even if it's based on a parameter. I did test this briefly but could not get it to work. It might be worth further investigation though as that would be a more elegant solution.